# Instalación Haystack - "Error: No module named apps"

Tags: python, django

Intento instalar Haystack en Django 1.4.7 pero cuando agrego Haystack a `INSTALLED_APPS` del `settings.py` me devuelve `"Error: No module named apps"`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'haystack',
'principal'

)
```

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionar este error?

Comment: Puedes poner el error completo?

Comment: Ese es el error "Error: No module named apps", no dice nada más la consola. Es poner 'haystack', en INSTALLED_APPS, correr Django y saltar ese error.

Comment: Quizá haystack no este bien instalado, o si estas usando virtualenv lo tengas instalado globalmente y no en el entorno. Si no es eso comprobaría que las versión de haystack sea compatible con la de Django.